# Web API - Get resource by IP address

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, get

I am trying to get a resource by providing ip address in GET request.

```
/api/computers/ip/192.168.10.90 - throws 404 error

/api/computers/ip/192~168~10~90 - hits the method
```

It looks like providing the IP is the issue here. So how do I pass IP as part of GET request?

Comment: Show the API method. What type of parameter you are using?

Comment: [HttpGet]
[Route("computers/ip/{ip}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetComputer(string ip)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to encode the ip address and pass it as a querystring value.
Your method will be

```
[Route("computers/ip")]
public IHttpActionResult GetComputer(string ip)
```

And you send the request : .../computers/ip?ip=[theEncodedIP]

You can remove the /ip from the method `Route`

```
[Route("computers")]
public IHttpActionResult GetComputer(string ip)
```

And you send the request using : .../computers?ip=[theEncodedIP]

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass ip in encoded form, but in querystring in Get request. You can do this by [HTTP handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227675(VS.80)) also, so if request matches the criteria you can use your logic before request goes to the server.

Some links have suggested to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests true in Web.Config.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Enabling RunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests will enable all managed modules for all requests. So resources like images, PDFs and everything else will be processed by server when they don't need to be.